# how to deploy python app on iis windows server?

Tags: python, windows, iis

hi i am trying to deploy my python app on windows2012 server with iis .
i follow the process of add application in website on specific folder than changing handler mapping settings in adding handler script putting python path in it.
when i am trying to open it code show me text of app.py instead of running it.

only difference when i tried is that in his python code he started with 
 #!iusr
and i started directly have my python code.
source where i tried
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7whncKjSXK0

anyone have any clue
thanks for help

Comment: is your issue resolved?

Answer (score 2):

First, create python site for example mine is hello.py and place it under C:\pythonsite folder:

```
print('Content-Type: text/plain')
print('')
print('Hello, world!')
```

- now open iis manager.
- add a new site. select your python site folder and add bindings.

[image]

- now click on the handler mapping from the middle pane.

[image]

- in the handler mapping window select "add script map" from the action pane.

[image]
 - add below details:

request path: *.py
executable: C:\Python37-32\python.exe %s %s
name:python

"C:\Python37-32\"  is your python folder.

[image]

- click request restrictions and make sure that the checkbox is unchecked.

[image]

- when you click on ok it will open a prompt click "yes".

[image]

Note: make sure directory browsing is enabled and your python and site folder has iis_iusrs and iusr permission assigned with full control. you install iis CGI feature.

- browse the site.

[image]